# How do I keep track of score within the functions of my python trivia game?

Tags: python

Let me start by saying that I am new to this and python is my first language so the simpler you can answer the better! Obviously, I cant put score += 1 into the conditional branch of each question's function because of errors with scope.  How would I go about keeping track of the score? Would I use another function for score itself?

Here is my code:

```
answer_a = ['A', 'a']
answer_b = ['B', 'b']
answer_c = ['C', 'c']
answer_d = ['D', 'd']
score = 0

def question1():
    print('What state contains the Statue of Liberty?'
          '\nA. California\nB. Rhode Island\nC. New York\nD. Florida')
    choice = input('> ')
    if choice in answer_c:
        print('\nCORRECT!\n') 
        question2()
    if choice in answer_a:
        print('Incorrect.\n')
        question2()
    if choice in answer_b:
        print('Incorrect.\n')
        question2()
    if choice in answer_d:
        print('Incorrect.\n')
        question2()
    else:
        print('Please select a valid input\n')
        question1()

def question2():
    pass
def question3():
    pass
```

Comment: You can declare `global scope` inside your `question1` function, and then you *can* use `scope += 1`.

Comment: you should send `score` to function as argument `def question(score)` and get it back with `return score` - so you could do `score = question(score)`

Comment: It looks like you're writing this as part of (homework) assignment? If you are, that's not a problem, but the assignment may want you to find specific solutions that we're not aware of and there's many ways to do what you're asking - just different design decisions and reasons. Looking at your code, it's clear that you're new to coding and there's many things to note, but I appreciate that you're looking for nice and clean ways of doing so - a word of advice: don't over-complicate things at first.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you can use global variables to keep track of values such as scores that keep on incrementing.

```
answer_a = ['A', 'a']
answer_b = ['B', 'b']
answer_c = ['C', 'c']
answer_d = ['D', 'd']
score = 0

def question1():
    global score   #global variable
    print('What state contains the Statue of Liberty?'
          '\nA. California\nB. Rhode Island\nC. New York\nD. Florida')
    choice = input('> ')
    if choice in answer_c:
        print('\nCORRECT!\n') 
        question2()
        score+=1
    elif choice in answer_a:
        print('Incorrect.\n')
        question2()
    elif choice in answer_b:
        print('Incorrect.\n')
        question2()
    elif choice in answer_d:
        print('Incorrect.\n')
        question2()
    else:
        print('Please select a valid input\n')
        question1()

    print("total score is", score)

def question2():
    pass
def question3():
    pass


question1()
```